# How do I delete Java application preferences?

Tags: macos, java

I am running Jabref v2.10 on Mac OS X 10.9.2. After changing some parts of the configuration file manually, I seem to have broken the preferences and now it fails to start. The application stores the application preferences using the java.util.prefs library. Is there a way I can delete java's stored preferences in Mac? (E.g., in linux, I would just delete the ~/.java folder)

Answer (score 4):

From [Apple Developer Connection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/05-CoreJavaAPIs/CoreJavaAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001902-210728-TPXREF143):

> The preferences files generated by the Preferences API are named com.apple.java.util.prefs. The user’s preferences file is stored in their home directory (~/Library/Preferences/). The system preferences are stored in  /Library/Preferences/ and are only persisted to disk if the user is an administrator.

I do not know if you can simply delete them though.

Comment: I had already tried deleting java, jabref specific files in ~/Library, but the problem had persisted. Apparently you need to restart your computer for changes to take place. (Seriously Oracle?) Anyways, that solves my problem

Comment: Good to know. :)

Comment: @kourbou I tried to delete this file, and reboot, but preferences are still present. Maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

This problem hit me recently so I thought I'd post the answer here belatedly.

When you delete the preferences on a Mac (`plist` file) make sure you clear the cached preferences otherwise Java programs can keep working with the cached settings.
You can:

1. Delete the `plist` file
2. `killall -u <your-user-name> cfprefsd`

   OR
3. reboot

Items 2. and 3. will cause the cache to be cleared and then your preferences will be reloaded as `cfprefsd` restarts automatically.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Java preference file is located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist` (for user).

You may try `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist`, but this does not exist on my computer. Since I cannot comment on previous answer and the link above is broken. I have to add an answer to clarify for the correct location.

I also have to say that this file contains all java-based applications' user data, so **make sure you know what you are doing if you try to delete it directly. Most of the time, you could open plist editor from XCode, and only delete the specific application related data.**